# Maybe monad usage example

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to learn Haskell but I'm having problem in monad usage.

I imported the module `Data.Maybe`.

But I don't know how to use the `>>=` operator.

Given `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` I cannot understand how to define a function `(a -> m b)`.

Can someone provide some pedagogical example?

Comment: The following provides an explanation: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads#Motivation:_Maybe

Comment: When you're reasoning about any function where you have `Monad m => ...` you can substitute m for the specific monad you're reasoning about. Hence, for Maybe, we have `(>>=) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b`. A function with return type `Maybe b` must return either `Just someB` or `Nothing`.

Comment: For future readers -  http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html is very illustrative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `Maybe` monad bind function (`>>=`) looks like that:

```
(>>=) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
```

So, let's define some `Maybe a` value:

```
> let a = Just 1
a :: Maybe Integer
```

And `:: a -> Maybe b` function:

```
> let f = \x -> Just (x+1)
f :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
```

Now we can use bind like infix operator:

```
> a >>= f
Just 2
it :: Maybe Integer
```

---

Another example of really `a -> Maybe b` function could be:

```
let h :: Integer -> Maybe String; h = return . show . (+1)
h :: Integer -> Maybe String
```

So `h` increment integer number, convert it to string and make a `Maybe` value
with `return` function.

```
> a >>= h
Just "2"
```

Comment: You could possibly demonstrate how "failure" propagates through. That is, the result of `Nothing >>= f`.

Answer (score 14):

A fairly common example with the Maybe monad is division. In some ways, the Maybe monad represents a computation that either gives a result (`Just`) or fails (`Nothing`), and division is precisely this: it works unless you are dividing by 0, in which case it is a failure.

Code is always useful:

```
divide :: (Fractional a) => a -> a -> Maybe a
divide a 0 = Nothing
divide a b = Just $ a / b
```

Some examples of using this function:

```
> divide 1 2
Just 0.5
> divide 20 3
Just 6.666666666666667
> divide 1 0 -- Oops
Nothing
```

Because Maybe is a monad, we can have computations that use this `divide` function and automatically propagate any errors. E.g. the following computes `1/x + 1` safely

```
recipPlusOne :: (Fractional a) => a -> Maybe a
recipPlusOne x = divide 1 x >>= return . (+1)

-- equivalently,
recipPlusOne' x = fmap (+1) $ divide 1 x
```

(Notice how `return . (+1)` is a function `a -> m b`, since it takes a number, adds one (`(+1)`), and then wraps it in the Maybe monad (`return`).)

And the errors propagate through,

```
> recipPlusOne 1
Just 2.0
> recipPlusOne 0.1
Just 11.0
> recipPlusOne 0 -- Oops, divide by 0
Nothing
```