# How can I handle an error from another function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm still a beginner in Haskell.

My code

```
secureDivide :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
secureDivide _ 0 = Nothing
secureDivide 0 _ = Nothing
secureDivide x y = Just (x `div` y)

addOne:: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
addOne (Just n) = Just (n + 1)
```

Actually I don't have any problem and get the result I want with 'secureDivide'.

Example : secureDivide 10 0  -> Nothing

But when I try something like this :

mySecureNext (mySecureDiv 10 0)  -> I have an **'Exception' and not 'Nothing'**

Is there a way to handle an error to a message without import something with the if-else statement like if error = Nothing else Just ... (or other option) ?

Comment: you need to handle the `Nothing` case in your `addOne` function. A better pattern is to simply define your `addOne` function as `Int -> Maybe Int`. Then you can utilize the fact that `Maybe` is a monad and do `secureDivide >>= addOne`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maybe monad usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881785/maybe-monad-usage-example)

Comment: Is `mySecureNext` supposed to be `addOne`?

Comment: `addOne  = fmap (+1)`. The definition of `fmap` takes care of both `Just` arguments and `Nothing` arguments. Your current definition duplicates the `Just` logic while ignoring the `Nothing` logic.

Comment: Also, you can drop `secureDivide 0 _ = Nothing`. There is no problem dividing 0 by a nonzero value, so it doesn't need to be caught and handled separately. (If you *do* handle it separately, the result should be `Just 0`, not `Nothing`.)

Answer (score 3):

In Data.Maybe there is function

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

Examples of use

```
maybe 0 (+1) Nothing
> 0
maybe 0 (+1) (Just 10)
> 11
```

### About addOne

a) You can add alternative variant of execution

```
addOne :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
addOne (Just n) = Just (n + 1)
addOne Nothing = Nothing

addOne (mySecureDiv 10 0)
```

b) You can change function to monadic function

```
addOne :: Int -> Maybe Int
addOne n = Just (n + 1)
```

And compose functions by

```
-- (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
-- or specific version
-- (>>=) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b

(mySecureDiv 10 0) >>= addOne
```

c) You can make pure function

```
addOne :: Int -> Int
addOne n = n + 1
```

And compose functions by

```
-- fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
-- or specific version
-- fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
-- or infix version <$>

fmap addOne (mySecureDiv 10 0)
addOne <$> (mySecureDiv 10 0)
```

Comment: The multiple ways to solve with a monad or with compose is super helpful. This really "clicked" in my brain. Thank you.